# Question about Macedonian Grammar

Tags: grammar, slavic-languages

I'm trying to learn Macedonian and one if the resources out there was paraphrased as saying the following about the Macedonian language:

> Belamaric-Wilsey says that the majority of Macedonian-language
>   learners using the center’s resources are English native speakers. The
>   most challenging features of the Macedonian language for them are the
>   doubling of the object, the verb aspect (perfective vs. imperfective),
>   and the perfect tense. Still, she says, if you are motivated enough,
>   you will make progress, especially if you are visiting Macedonia.

What does this mean?

- Doubling of the Object
- Verb aspect (Perfective vs. Imperfective)
- Perfect tense

And, how does Macedonian's handling of the concepts differ from English's?

Comment: Perfective and imperfective are standard names for two commonly occurring aspects, and perfect tense for a commonly occurring tense; you can read what all three are on Wikipedia. What Macedonian does with them that makes them challenging is more on-topic; unfortunately I don’t know the answer. Doubling the object usually refers to using both a pronoun and a noun for the object (“I saw him my brother”); Spanish does it a lot for indirect object (“_Le_ di un libro _a mi hermano_” = “I gave him my brother a book”). I don’t know if it refers to something else in Macedonian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take the following sentence as an example that includes all your points:

**Јаc   сум ја прочитал       книгата.**
*Jas sum ja pro=čita-l     kniga-ta.*
I<sub>1</sub>   am<sub>2</sub>    3-sing-fem-acc-clitic<sub>3</sub>   perf=read-past<sub>4</sub>   book-the<sub>5</sub>
'I read the book."

It exhibits:

1. Clitic doubling: the presence of both the direct object *книгата* and the direct object pronoun *ја*.
2. Verbal aspect: the perfective form *прочитал* 'pročital' is used indicating the action of reading the book was completed. If the reading of the book wasn't complete, the form would be  *читал* 'čital'.
3. The perfect tense: In English we use "to have" + past participle of verb to indicate the perfect. In Macedonian, there are two forms of the present perfect each for perfective verbs and imperfective verbs (total of 4 present perfect complex tenses):

   - one each formed with сум 'to be' + L-form of the verb (*прочитал / читал*)
   - one each formed with имам 'to have' + neuter adjective form of verb (*прочитано / читано*)

So in addition to the form above "*Јаc сум ја прочитал книгата.*", one could also say "*Јас  ја  имам прочитано книгата.*" for "I read the book". I don't know enough about Macedonian to say what the difference in meaning might be between the sum-perfect and the imam-perfect. There is also a past perfect and a future perfect in Macedonian as well, so it does take a bit of work learning.